# How I can use CTE table more then one time

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
With CTETable as
(
   select * from table
)

Select * from CTETable --one time

Select sum(column) from CTETable -- 2nd time

Select count(column) from CTETable -- 3rd time
```

Please help.

Comment: you can't. You can (on sufficiently modern versions) include `SUM`s and `COUNT` across the entire result set using the partition functions. You'll end up with a single result set with the same sum and count in every row. If that's acceptable, say so (also, indicate your SQL Server version)

Comment: Use VIEW instead of CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use CTE in more than one query. But alternatively you can use it by making another CTE for Sum or Count purpose from existing CTE and cross join them.

see below query.

```
With CTETable as
(
   select * from Table
), CTETotal As 
(
   SELECT COUNT(count) 'count' 
   from CTETable
) 
Select * from CTETable 
CROSS JOIN CTETotal
```

Answer (score 1):

A CTE can only be used in one query. So just join the individual queries with `UNION ALL` into one query. You can use an additional, artificial row to distinguish between the different result sets.

See [here for a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87884/4):

```
With CTETable as
(
   select * from TestTable
)
Select '*',* from CTETable --one time
UNION ALL
Select 'sum', sum(col) from CTETable -- 2nd time
UNION ALL
Select 'count', count(col) from CTETable -- 3rd time
```

Comment: @MuhammadADIL Then no, you can't do this with a CTE. A CTE can only be used in a single subsequent query. The benefit of doing so is not what you think it might be, anyway; it is not a #temp table. When you reference the CTE multiple times (e.g. in the UNION above), the CTE can be evaluated that many times.

Comment: Thanks stefan.schwetschke but it is not help full for me. please give me another suggestion

Comment: I am doing this task with Variable tables, it is working fine but CTE table we can't use more then one :(

Comment: Also, this breaks as soon as there is more than one column in the source table as the unions will have differing numbers of columns.